# Git post-commit hook as a background task

Tags: git, shell, sh, post-commit, gitx

I have a script, that I need to run after committing to a project under git revision control. Therefore I created a post-commit hook in my projects .git directory in the subdirectory /hooks, named it 'post-commit' and gave it the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
# I am a post-commit hook
/usr/local/bin/my_script &
```

my_script is executable and runs fine in /bin/sh. In fact it has a runtime of several seconds, so I want it to be backgrounded and detached from the current shell. That's why I put the trailing '&' to my hook.

The problem now is, that the '&' seems to be ignored. When I commit using gitx 0.7.1 under OSX Lion, gitx hangs for exactly the period that my_script needs to run.

I tried a lot, but do not get the process itself into the background.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's how it works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
# I am a post-commit hook
nohup /usr/local/bin/my_script &>/dev/null &
```

Comment: David, meanwhile I found a similar approach: nohup /usr/local/bin/my_script 2>&1 > /dev/null &

Comment: Not exactly the correct answer, but will guide some people: consider implementing a real daemon. If in ruby you can use Daemons or read the basics of what you should be doing in this description of how a daemon works in unix: http://daemons.rubyforge.org/Daemons.html

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the `at` command. You may have to install it first

```
echo /path/to/your/executable | at now
```

**OR:**

```
echo bash /path/to/your/script | at now
```

See the at(1) manual page for more info about at (`man at` or [the online version](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at))

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

```
#!/bin/sh
# I am a post-commit hook
nohup /usr/local/bin/my_script &
```

Comment: Hey WagnerVaz, tried that, but unfortunately it does not work. The script seems not to detach from the current process and gitx is stale as long as the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

If you change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` (assuming you're ok with using bash), and use `nohup`, your example should work.